# Update text layer in psd file in C#

Tags: c#, layer, psd

I want to update a specific text layer of psd file (always the same (find with his name)) in C#.
I searched and tested a lot of libraries which didn't working.
Recently, I found this library on GitHub : https://github.com/bizzehdee/System.Drawing.PSD

I downloaded sources, try it and in C#, I can access to my specifid layer, but, I can't update it.
In Layer class, there are differents attributs but I don't control them.

I wan't to know if there is anybody who can test it and help me to understand the library.
I asked the author but his last action is in last year...

I hope you can help me !

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, have you got solution for this?

Comment: Hello,

Not yet... I'm speaking with the article author and I will write here if I have a solution.

But if anyone can help us too...

Answer (score 1):

You can try Aspose.PSD. It supports simple text layer editing and editing text layer by portions: https://docs.aspose.com/display/psdnet/Working+With+Text+Layers

```
// Load a PSD file as an image and cast it into PsdImage
using (PsdImage psdImage = (PsdImage)Image.Load(dataDir + "layers.psd"))
{
    foreach (var layer in psdImage.Layers)
    {
        if (layer is TextLayer)
        {
            TextLayer textLayer = layer as TextLayer;
            textLayer.UpdateText("test update", new Point(0, 0), 15.0f, Color.Purple);
        }
    }

    psdImage.Save(dataDir + "UpdateTextLayerInPSDFile_out.psd");
}
```

Example with Text Portions:

```
string sourceFile = dataDir + "text212.psd";
string outputFile = dataDir + "Output_text212.psd";

using (var img = (PsdImage)Image.Load(sourceFile))
{
    TextLayer textLayer = (TextLayer)img.Layers[1];
    IText textData = textLayer.TextData;
    ITextStyle defaultStyle = textData.ProducePortion().Style;
    ITextParagraph defaultParagraph = textData.ProducePortion().Paragraph;
    defaultStyle.FillColor = Color.DimGray;
    defaultStyle.FontSize = 51;

    textData.Items[1].Style.Strikethrough = true;

    ITextPortion[] newPortions = textData.ProducePortions(new string[]
    {
        "E=mc", "2\r", "Bold", "Italic\r",
        "Lowercasetext"
    },
    defaultStyle,
    defaultParagraph);

    newPortions[0].Style.Underline = true; // edit text style "E=mc"
    newPortions[1].Style.FontBaseline = FontBaseline.Superscript; // edit text style "2\r"
    newPortions[2].Style.FauxBold = true; // edit text style "Bold"
    newPortions[3].Style.FauxItalic = true; // edit text style "Italic\r"
    newPortions[3].Style.BaselineShift = -25; // edit text style "Italic\r"
    newPortions[4].Style.FontCaps = FontCaps.SmallCaps; // edit text style      "Lowercasetext"

    foreach (var newPortion in newPortions)
    {
         textData.AddPortion(newPortion);
    }

    textData.UpdateLayerData();
    img.Save(outputFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont use Aspose because it's not free for use.

All you need is AdobeStandard.COM-component.

```cs
Photoshop.Application app = new Photoshop.Application();
Photoshop.Document doc = app.Open(@"test.psd");

for(int i = 1; i <= doc.ArtLayers.Count; i++)
{
    string name = doc.ArtLayers[i].Name;
    
    if (name.Equals("Title1"))
    {
        doc.ArtLayers[i].TextItem.Contents = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use can use the trial version of Aspose.PSD since it is free during the trial period.